# How to retrieve latest instance using IF else condition in sqldeveloper

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have one student table which is given below

---

```
ROLL  |  STUDENT | SUBJECT | VERSION_ID |

  1        A         M         1
  2        B         M         2 
  3        C         M         3
  4        B         S         1
  5        D         S         2
  6        E         E         1 
  7        F         G         1
```

**If there is atleast one record for SUBJECT='M' then retrieve latest record for SUBJECT 'M' based on version id.

ELSIF  If there is atleast one record for SUBJECT='S' then retrieve latest record for SUBJECT 'S' based on version id.

ELSIF  If there is atleast one record for SUBJECT='E' then retrieve latest record for SUBJECT 'E' based on version id.

Else   DO NOT fetch any record.**

Based on above condition I am trying to write a query or view which can satisfy all above condition and and give below output. Please suggest me possible solutions to get this.

**Output**

```
ROLL  |  STUDENT | SUBJECT | VERSION_ID | 
  3        C         M         3
```

I have tried to get desired output using below query but I encountered with error. Please help me to solve this query with better performance.

```
SELECT * from ( IF EXISTS(select subject from STUDENT where SUBJECT='M') then
select * from STUDENT S1
inner join
(select S2.ROLL from STUDENT S2
      where 
          S2.ROLL=(select S3.ROLL from STUDENT S3
                       where S3.SUBJECT='M'
                   and S3.VERSION_ID=(select MAX(S4.VERSION_ID) from STUDENT S4
                           GROUP BY S4.SUBJECT
                           HAVING S4.SUBJECT='M'))) S5
ON
S1.ROLL=S5.ROLL
ELSIF EXISTS(select subject from STUDENT where SUBJECT='S') then
select * from STUDENT S1
inner join
(select S2.ROLL from STUDENT S2
      where 
          S2.ROLL=(select S3.ROLL from STUDENT S3
                       where S3.SUBJECT='S'
                   and S3.VERSION_ID=(select MAX(S4.VERSION_ID) from STUDENT S4
                           GROUP BY S4.SUBJECT
                           HAVING S4.SUBJECT='S'))) S5
           ON
          S1.ROLL=S5.ROLL
ELSIF EXISTS(select subject from STUDENT where SUBJECT='E') then
select * from STUDENT S1
inner join
(select S2.ROLL from STUDENT S2
      where 
          S2.ROLL=(select S3.ROLL from STUDENT S3
                       where S3.SUBJECT='E'
                   and S3.VERSION_ID=(select MAX(S4.VERSION_ID) from STUDENT S4
                           GROUP BY S4.SUBJECT
                           HAVING S4.SUBJECT='E'))) S5
           ON
          S1.ROLL=S5.ROLL
ELSE 
  SELECT * FROM STUDENT WHERE 1=2);
```

**TABLE CREATION:**

```
Create table student (ROLL number,STUDENT varchar2(20),SUBJECT varchar2(20),VERSION_ID number );
```

**Insert Data:**

```
insert into STUDENT values(1,'A','M',1);
insert into STUDENT values(2,'B','M',2);
insert into STUDENT values(3,'C','M',3);
insert into STUDENT values(4,'B','S',1);
insert into STUDENT values(5,'D','S',2);
insert into STUDENT values(6,'E','E',1);
insert into STUDENT values(7,'F','G',1);
```

Thank You..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can apply `ROW_NUMBER` to entire table, using the ordering logic you gave in your question.  Subjects `M`, `S`, and `E` have priority, in that order, with the `VERSION_ID` breaking the tie.  Rows with a subject not matching these three are assigned the lowest priority.  Should there be no records with matching subjects, we filter out all records in the `WHERE` clause.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT ROLL, STUDENT, SUBJECT, VERSION_ID,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CASE WHEN SUBJECT = 'M' THEN 1
                                         WHEN SUBJECT = 'S' THEN 2
                                         WHEN SUBJECT = 'E' THEN 3
                                         ELSE 4 END, VERSION_ID DESC END) rn
)

SELECT ROLL, STUDENT, SUBJECT, VERSION_ID
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1 AND SUBJECT IN ('M', 'S', 'E')
```

Comment: Hi Tim, Thanks for your quick response. In this case this query will give expected output. But if **Subject M** is not available then query should give latest record for **subject S**  i.e. `5 , 'D', 'S',  2 ` . IF both Subject 'M' and 'S' are not in table then query should check for Subject 'E' , i.e.  `6, 'E', 'E', 1` . Will this query work in all condition?

Comment: @jhulan Yes, I believe it will.  Have you tested my query yet?  If you find it actually fails for some edge case, then drop a comment and it can be updated.

Comment: Thank you Tim, This is working fine. sorry , I commented without testing and this is very simple and short solution.

Answer (score 0):

You want right answer right? Try this :

```
SELECT TOP 1 #student.*
FROM   student
JOIN   (

SELECT  MAX(VERSION_ID) VERSION_ID,SUBJECT
FROM   student
WHERE  SUBJECT = 'M'
GROUP BY SUBJECT

UNION ALL 

SELECT  MAX(VERSION_ID),SUBJECT
FROM   student
WHERE  SUBJECT = 'S'
GROUP BY SUBJECT

UNION ALL

SELECT  MAX(VERSION_ID),SUBJECT
FROM   student
WHERE  SUBJECT = 'E'
GROUP BY SUBJECT

UNION ALL 

SELECT  MAX(VERSION_ID),SUBJECT
FROM   student
WHERE  SUBJECT = 'G'
GROUP BY SUBJECT

UNION ALL

SELECT NULL,NULL

)       AS Dtls
ON     (student.SUBJECT     =      Dtls.SUBJECT
AND student.VERSION_ID     =      Dtls.VERSION_ID)
```

Comment: Useful for someone I'm sure, but the question is tagged as Oracle, which doesn't have `top 1`. (It has `fetch first row only` but the question is also tagged Oracle 10g which is an ancient version that didn't have this either.)